# How do I get the mean function to work in R studio?

Tags: r

```
as.numeric(moma_artists_alive$Age)
moma_artists_alive%>%
  filter(Alive == "Yes")%>%
  group_by(Gender)%>%
  summarise(av_age = mean(Age))
```

This is my code to work out the average age, I have also tried putting in na.rm = TRUE and it doesn't seem to work and gives me an Na

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput` if `mean(Age, na.rm = TRUE)` is not working?  In the first line, you convert the 'Age' to `numeric`, but it is not assigned back i.e. `moma_artists_alive$Age <- as.numeric(moma_artists_alive$Age)`.   Another option is `mean(as.numeric(Age), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: I assigned it back and it worked. Thanks so much